# What is the problem about my fibonacci python code?

Tags: python, fibonacci

If you could look at my code.

```py
numbers = [1,2]
times = int(input("How many numbersM (minimum is 2)"))
def fibonacci(numbers, times):
    for i in range(0, times):
        for j in numbers:
            numbers.append( numbers[j] + numbers[j+1])
        print(numbers[i])
fibonacci(numbers, times)
```

Comment: You tell us, what error or output are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: just change `for j in numbers` to `for j in range(len(numbers))` and it will be OK.

Comment: @finefoot, Oh you are right. I just saw his/her mistake of taking `for i in L` as indexes, so just commented to point out for indexed you should do `for i in range(len(L))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your code like that, you will get

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

because `for j in numbers:` is a loop over the values in `numbers` which contains value `1` which is an index out of range when you try to access `numbers[j+1]` because there is no `numbers[2]` at this point. Why do you need that second `for` loop in there anyway? You will access the last and second-to-last values with `numbers[i]` and `numbers[i+1]`. No need to loop over the other values of your list.

I have removed that loop and if you run your code like this:

```py
numbers = [1,2]
times = int(input("How many numbersM (minimum is 2)"))
def fibonacci(numbers, times):
    for i in range(0, times):
        numbers.append( numbers[i] + numbers[i+1])
        print(numbers[i])
fibonacci(numbers, times)
```

You'll get something like this, for example:

```
How many numbersM (minimum is 2)5
1
2
3
5
8
```